# Test for very small sample sizes?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, biostatistics

I did home range estimations with 4 individuals and I struggle to find a proper test to test if they differ significantly.

My data looks like that:

```r
    MCP100 <- c(4.51, 7.98, 8.03, 5.40)
    KDE95 <- c(1.87, 1.34, 1.74, 0.92)
    KDE50 <- c(0.378, 0.283, 0.357, 0.170)
    numberofareasKDE95 <- c(19, 30, 17, 30)
    peroverlapMCP100 <- c(42.63, 36.22, 61.38, 3.10) # percentage
```

Someone said I could do a **Chi² test**, but I think a Chi² test can only be done with frequencies. Am I wrong?

I tried to do a **t-test**, but that doesn't work out really, because the t-test for one sample only compares data with a given mean (or 0 for default and that doesn't make sense either).

I also have percentage data which is calculated by the size of the overlapping area in relation to the size of the home range.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Can you explain what the five variables represent?

Comment: MCP100, KDE95 and KDE50 are home range size in hectar. numberofareasKDE95 is the number of areas in KDE95 (to check how clustered or fragmented it is) and peroverlapMCP100 is the relation between the size of the overlapping area with other individuals in relation to home range size.

Comment: When you ask whether "home range[s] ... differ significantly" you need also to specify: "differ in which measure" (e.g., each of MCP100, KDE95, etc., or some measure of home range that combines all those characteristics) and "differ with respect to what" (e.g., differences among individuals having specified characteristics). With only 1 set of observations on each individual and only 4 individuals, it will be hard to establish statistical significance in any event. Even your estimates of the inter-individual variability of each of the characteristics will be imprecise.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do statistical tests for individual differences of MCP100 etc.. So, even if it would be imprecise, would a Chi² test be possible?